# Calculo de temperatura por trismestre com python

Tags: python

Boa tarde.
Estou começando a estudar python, e preciso realizar o calculo de temperatura por trimestre, e imprimir os meses do trimestre com a média de temperatura. Cheguei no código abaixo, porem não consigo sair dele. Poderiam me dar uma ajuda?

```
meses = [
    "janeiro",
    "fevereiro",
    "março",
    "abril",
    "maio",
    "junho",
    "julho",
    "agosto",
    "setembro",
    "outubro",
    "novembro",
    "dezembro",
]
cidade = (input(f"Digite a cidade: "))
temperaturas = []

for i in range(12):
    temperaturas.append(float(input(f"Digite a temperatura de {meses[i]} em ºC: ")))
    media = sum(temperaturas) / 12

for i in range(0,len(meses)):
  print(f"\n Temperatura na cidade de {cidade} no mes de {meses[i]} foi de ")

print(f"\nA média das temperaturas foi {media:.2f}ºC")
```

Comment: Qual o problema específico que você está enfrentando?

Comment: Não estou sabendo como fazer para pegar os trimestres e fazer a media dos mesmos.

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! 

Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Comment: Vc precisa quebrar os arrays em pedaços de 3 elementos e calcular as médias de cada um desses pedaços: https://ideone.com/W7E3ZW

Comment: Outra alternativa é ter uma lista de trimestres (ou seja, uma lista contendo 4 sub-listas, e cada uma dessas sub-listas contém temperaturas de um dos trimestres): https://ideone.com/A1yWKn (similar à resposta abaixo)

Answer (score -2):

Seu código tem alguns probleminhas, mas respondendo especificamente à sua dúvida eu sugiro a seguinte solução usando uma lista temporária:

```
meses = [
    "janeiro",
    "fevereiro",
    "março",
    "abril",
    "maio",
    "junho",
    "julho",
    "agosto",
    "setembro",
    "outubro",
    "novembro",
    "dezembro",
]
cidade = (input(f"Digite a cidade: "))
lista_trimestres, lista_temp = [], []
x = 0

for i in range(12):
    y = float(input(f"Digite a temperatura de {meses[i]} em ºC: "))
    if x !=3:
        lista_temp.append(y)
        x+=1
        if x == 3:
            lista_trimestres.append(lista_temp)
            lista_temp = []
            x = 0

for i in range(0,len(lista_trimestres)):
  print(f"\n A Temperatura média do {i+1}º trimestre foi de {sum(lista_trimestres[i])/3:.2f} ºC")
```

O que fiz foi criar uma lista de listas para guardar as temperaturas separadas por trimestre. Cada trimestre vai ser uma lista que é delimitada/controlada pelo valor de `x`.

Repare no segundo `if` dentro do `for`. É ele que controla quando a lista auxiliar deve ser acidionada à listas de trimestres e quando os valores devem ser zerados.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando. Estudar mais e mais, e espero colaborar muito com a comunidade de python! Obrigado